# Laravel retrieve status from pivot table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i have tables ,Station & Equipment ,a third pivot table station_equipment with additional field "status" besides the respective table ids, the status can be active or inactive, I just want to get the Active elements, but my query keep on retrieving equipments with both status .

the query:

```
   $eqestacion = Station::where('station.id', $id)
                ->whereHas('equipments', function($query) {

                    $query->where('equipment_station.status','=','active');
                    })->with('equipments')
                      ->get();
```

Station Model:

```
public function equipments(){

  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Equipment')->withPivot('status')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Equiment Model:

```
 public function stations()

   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Station')
    ->orderBy('pivot_created_at','desc')->withPivot('status')->withTimestamps();
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you a `Station` with id `$id`:

```
$station = Station::findOrFail($id);
```

This will give you all active `Equipments` associated to the `$station`.

```
$station->equipments()->wherePivot('status', 'active')->get();
```

Comment: how could i get the station data too?